# Best place to implement the subscribe of an observable in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I'm developing an app using angular in the FrontEnd and I'm calling rest services with http client and I want to know where is the best place to implement the subscribe of the httpClient.get() 's observable in the service or in the component.ts?

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/

Comment: There is no "best place". It depends. Bear in mind that services are singletons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a service that holds logic for calling an api.
in your service file

```
Abc(): Observable<any>{ // 'any' to be replaced by type
  return this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

in your component file

```
    this.Service.Abc().subscribe(
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to not subscribe at all.

1) Create a method in service which returns the observable

```
getAll(): Observable<MyData[]> {
  return this.http<MyData[]>.get(PATH_TO_GET_ALL_ENDPOINT);
}
```

2) call this method in component and store the Observable

```
allData$: Observable<MyData[]> = this.myService.getAll();
```

3) Use async pipe in template to "Subscribe"

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allData$ | async as allData; else pending">
  <div *ngFor="let data of allData">{{ data | json }}</div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #pending>pending...</ng-template>
```